# ESLint TypeScript Parsing Error for Cypress Configuration File in WebStorm

Tags: typescript, cypress, eslint, webstorm, tsconfig

I'm working on a TypeScript project in WebStorm and have integrated ESLint for linting. My project includes Cypress for end-to-end testing, and I've encountered a parsing error when ESLint tries to run on my `cypress.config.ts` file. The error message suggests that my `tsconfig.json` does not include this file, leading to ESLint configuration issues. Here is the error message I receive:

```
Parsing error: ESLint was configured to run on `<tsconfigRootDir>/cypress.config.ts` using `parserOptions.project`: tsconfig.json
However, that TSConfig does not include this file. Either:
- Change ESLint's list of included files to not include this file
- Change that TSConfig to include this file
- Create a new TSConfig that includes this file and include it in your parserOptions.project
See the typescript-eslint docs for more info: https://typescript-eslint.io/linting/troubleshooting#i-get-errors-telling-me-eslint-was-configured-to-run--however-that-tsconfig-does-not--none-of-those-tsconfigs-include-this-file
```

I understand from the error that the `cypress.config.ts` is not covered by the `tsconfig.json` specified in ESLint's `parserOptions.project`. I've looked into the suggested options but I'm unsure how to properly configure either ESLint or the TSConfig to resolve this issue without affecting the rest of my project setup.

Could anyone provide guidance or a detailed solution on how to adjust my ESLint and TypeScript configurations to fix this parsing error, specifically for a WebStorm environment?

Modifying ESLint Included Files: I attempted to adjust the ESLint configuration to exclude cypress.config.ts from analysis by modifying the included files list, utilizing the overrides section in the ESLint configuration file to set rules for specific file patterns.

Altering TSConfig: I also tried including cypress.config.ts in the tsconfig.json by editing the include array, adding "cypress.config.ts" alongside my existing paths.

Creating and Using a Separate TSConfig: Considering a more targeted approach, I created a separate tsconfig.json file specifically for files like cypress.config.ts. This new config, named tsconfig.eslint.json, extends the original tsconfig.json and includes additional files for ESLint to analyze.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.